# Question about building MS SQL query with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a query in MS SQL, with many joins to get the needed data for the products from 5 tables. I want to upgrade the query and to get the products grouped by Part_number and to get the Unit_Price for the latest date based on column Document_Date.

On the left is the example DP table on the right is the target table.
The main purpose is to save the joins in the current query, to group the products by Part_Number column and to get the Unit_Price for the latest date for each product

[image: Example Table and Target Table in Excel]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Include the query as *text* in your question.  Explain the logic clearly.

Comment: And please do include data as text also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest row for each product, you can use `row_number()`:

```
with q as (<your query here>)
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by part_number order by document_date desc) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum = 1;
```